# Is chromecast API working with packaged apps?

Tags: google-bigquery, chromecast, google-chrome-app

I created Google packaged app (not extension). Now i am going to use chromecast device. Is chromecast API working with packaged apps?

Answer (score 3):

Currently this is not supported but it is on our radar to provide support in future.

Comment: Thanks. So operation with whitelistening of chrome apps is only for extension ?